# How to add input field in views fields?

Tags: views, google-maps

I have to store some hidden values in each views rows (**To store Latitude and Longitude of Gmap Locations**). How to add a input hidden field in Views Field. I tried bartik_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) but it is not invoked.

Comment: Do you want to hide the values from the screen but want to keep it in browser?

Comment: @SumitMadan yes!

Answer (score 0):

I added the latitude and longitude in views fields and overwritten the global: Custom Text field with the replacement tokens and added "element-hidden" class so that value will be there in views in hidden. Any other Solutions?

Comment: Thats it. You need the same. Or you can add these classes to the lat long fields so no need to add custom text field. :)

Comment: Yeah that would be more simple.